# Jetpack Compose animation is jumping

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I'm trying to add a fade in/fade out animation to switch between 2 views but the animation is jumping when I run it on the simulator.

I've added x2 `AnimatedVisibility` to switch between each of the views in my `SignInOrSignUpMasterView`.

How can I fix this?

```
class SignInOrSignUp : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyAppTheme {
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    SignInOrSignUpMasterView()
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
    

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//SignInOrSignUpMethod enum
enum class SignInOrSignUpMethod {
    Google,
    EmailOnly
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//SignInOrSignUpViewModel
class SignInOrSignUpViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var signInOrSignUpMethod: SignInOrSignUpMethod by mutableStateOf(SignInOrSignUpMethod.EmailOnly)
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//SignInOrSignUpMasterView
@Composable
fun SignInOrSignUpMasterView(
    signInOrSignUpViewModel: SignInOrSignUpViewModel = viewModel()
) {

    Box {
        //Background image
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.sign_in_sign_up_background),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            alpha = 0.50F,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.White)
                .fillMaxSize()
        )


        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally

        ) {
            //App Logo
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.app_logo),
                contentDescription = null,
                colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(
                    (if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                        Color.Black
                    } else {
                        Color.White
                    })
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(125.dp, 125.dp)
                    .offset(0.dp, 50.dp)
            )


            //Spacer to fill the rest of screen to position the buttons at the bottom of the screen
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))


            //Sign In/Up Views
            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = signInOrSignUpViewModel.signInOrSignUpMethod == SignInOrSignUpMethod.Google,
                enter = fadeIn(),
                exit = fadeOut()
            ) {
                SignInOrSignUpWithGoogleView()
            }

            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = signInOrSignUpViewModel.signInOrSignUpMethod == SignInOrSignUpMethod.EmailOnly,
                enter = fadeIn(),
                exit = fadeOut()
            ) {
                SignInOrSignUpWithEmailAddressView()
            }

            Spacer(Modifier.height(10.dp))

            Text("Legal information")

            Spacer(Modifier.height(40.dp))

        }
    }

}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//SignInOrSignUpWithGoogleView
@Composable
fun SignInOrSignUpWithGoogleView(
    signInOrSignUpViewModel: SignInOrSignUpViewModel = viewModel()
) {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp)
    ) {

        Text("Sign in with Google view")

        ClickableText(
            text = AnnotatedString("Continue with email address"),
            onClick = {
                signInOrSignUpViewModel.signInOrSignUpMethod = SignInOrSignUpMethod.EmailOnly
            },
            style = TextStyle(
                fontSize = 15.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                color = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                    Color.Black
                } else {
                    Color.White
                }
            )
        )

    }

}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//SignInOrSignUpWithEmailAddressView
@Composable
fun SignInOrSignUpWithEmailAddressView(
    signInOrSignUpViewModel: SignInOrSignUpViewModel = viewModel()
) {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp)
    ) {

        Text("Sign in with email address view")

        ClickableText(
            text = AnnotatedString("Continue with Google"),
            onClick = {
                signInOrSignUpViewModel.signInOrSignUpMethod = SignInOrSignUpMethod.Google
            },
            style = TextStyle(
                fontSize = 15.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                color = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                    Color.Black
                } else {
                    Color.White
                }
            )
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share a video of current behaviour and expected behaviour

Comment: @NikhilDupally I can't upload a video to StackOverflow.  Are you able to copy and paste my code and replace the images with your own (they aren't really important to  the animation though)

Answer (score 0):

You Should Wrap your animated visibility in a box because if they are in a column the column will allocate space for the showing view while the other one is fading away resulting in a janky animation.

```kotlin
Box {
// Wrap your Animated Visibility in a Box
// Sign In/Up Views
    androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = signInOrSignUpViewModel.signInOrSignUpMethod == SignInOrSignUpMethod.Google,
        enter = fadeIn(),
        exit = fadeOut()
    ) {
        SignInOrSignUpWithGoogleView()
    }
    androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = signInOrSignUpViewModel.signInOrSignUpMethod == SignInOrSignUpMethod.EmailOnly,
        enter = fadeIn(),
        exit = fadeOut()
    ) {
        SignInOrSignUpWithEmailAddressView()
    }
}
```

## Update

```kotlin
Box {
    val googleAlpha by animateFloatAsState(
        if (signInOrSignUpViewModel.signInOrSignUpMethod == SignInOrSignUpMethod.Google) 1f
        else 0f
    )
    val emailAlpha by animateFloatAsState(
        if (signInOrSignUpViewModel.signInOrSignUpMethod == SignInOrSignUpMethod.EmailOnly) 1f
        else 0f
    )
    SignInOrSignUpWithGoogleView(
        modifier = Modifier.alpha(googleAlpha)
    )
    SignInOrSignUpWithEmailAddressView(
        modifier = Modifier.alpha(emailAlpha)
    )
}
```

Comment: This is better, but there is still some jumping.  My `SignInOrSignUpWithGoogleView()` only has a button, whereas my `SignInOrSignUpWithEmailAddressView()` has a textfield and a button, so is slightly taller.

Comment: Then you can use the alpha modifier instead of the animated visibility

Comment: Can you show how I'd do this please?

Comment: I updated the answer take a look at it and tell me if it works

Comment: I've got the code to compile and run, but when I click on the `ClickableText` to switch between the views, the app crashes.